# Failed on building working RegEx Expression

Tags: c#, regex

i'm currently working on a small searching tool, which searchs for defined words in every (text-based) file in a selected filepath.

Therefore i used to build a working RegEx String which makes this possible and also mostly does.

Furthermore, i added a function where the user can add Strings to a List, wich should be excluded from the searched word (e.g. SearchString: "result", exlusion:":=", so that "result:=" in .dfm Files should be ignored).

My current RegEx String is :

```
@"(?:(result)(?!:=|;))"
```

This solution works simple, if there's only ":=" or ";" at the end of "result". But it should be allowed that other words can stand for- and afterwards "result" till the end of the line.

Can anybody help me? :)

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: @poke @"(?:(searchedword)(?! exlusion1|exlusion2|exlusionN)"
This works if the exlusion follows on the searched word. If i put it in front like: (@"(?:(?!exclusion1|exlusion2)(searchedword)(?! exlusion1|exlusion2|exlusionN)" it still matches. Why? Is there another solution instead of: @"(?:([^exlusion]searchedword)(?! exlusion1|exlusion2|exlusionN)"

Comment: No, of the texts you want to match and those you don’t want to match. Your description is not really clear.

Comment: Well okay... 
Word i want to match: "result" ("" are not part of the  String)
what should not be matched: "result:=" or "@result" or any other mutation of "result"
So i want to build a variable RegEx String in C# which makes this possible

Comment: Other words and signs in for and afterwards to "result" should be allowed

Comment: You need a clearer definition of "any other mutation of result".  However `\bresult\b` will take you part of the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a negative lookbehind `(?<!)`

```
(?<!@|&)result(?!:=|;)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/32)